api call still uses modem connection even when routing table metric is lower for wifi
I have a .Net 8 Core app running on a raspberry Pi with Debian OS.
I can make an internet conenction using a WIFI apn of a modem/GPRS connection.
I have an API that makes an API call every 30 seconds to my server.
I have an image upload to the same server using a UDP connection.
If the modem is not available i.e no signal etc the the UDP switches automatically to WIFI (if that is available). But the Web API call still tries to connect using the GPRS/Modem connection (and fails).
If I change the Tables to favor the Wan device like so:

Then all works OK.
Any reason why the API call tries to connection using the UBS/Modem device?
